# Make text between asterisks bold

Tags: php, str-replace

I wanted to make a PHP function that would make text bold between double asterisks, and italic between one asterisk, *(quite like the editor on stackoverflow)*.

Same rules apply, if there's a space between the * and the word, it shouldn't render.

Who can help me out?
I tried to, but I only came this far, as I don't know how to make the odd asterisks "< b >" and the even ones "< /b >".

*(I can't type them without the spaces, stackoverflow will render the text between as bold.....)*

```
$thenewtext = str_replace("**", "<b>", "**Hello World** of PHP");
```

Comment: Regular expressions will work for this simple example.  But please consider choosing a parser.  Using regular expressions with HTML [can drive some people to drink](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13895).

Comment: @John:  OP seems to be transforming plain text *into* HTML, not parsing HTML, so regular expressions should be just fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple regex will do the trick:

```
$thenewtext = preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', '<b>$1</b>', '**Hello World** of PHP');
```

Comment: `'#\*{2}([^*]*)\*{2}#'` would be a little faster.

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't allow me to have a bold string containing three asterisks.  Should it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's show some fringe cases in the input.
In my snippet, I'll be using lookarounds to ensure that asterisks are not greater than 2 and that a space is not permitted just inside the beginning/ending double-asterisks.

There is some subjective interpretation as to how these fringe cases should be handled, but I can at least say that this pattern makes an attempt to replace the space-disqualification that is demanded in the posted question.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HRquk))

```
$string = 'start ** not bold ** and **bold** not bold **bold *** still bold** not bold **** not bold ****';
// bad space------⬏
// completely valid triple asterisk should not break styling-⬏
// more than 2 consecutive asterisks should not trigger styling?----------------------⬏⬏

echo preg_replace('/(?<!\*)\*\*(?![\s*])(.*?)(?<![\s*])\*\*(?!\*)/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```

Output:

```
start ** not bold ** and <b>bold</b> not bold <b>bold *** still bold</b> not bold **** not bold ****
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not too familiar with it but you are going to need a Regular Expression. Look into [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

I recently implemented a server-side text highlighting system to complement jQuery UI's AutoComplete.

My adaptation of your idea would be something like this:

```
$txt = 'not bold [BeginBold]Yes Bold[EndBold] not bold again';

$newtxt = str_replace("[BeginBold]", "<b>", $txt);
$newtxt = str_replace("[EndBold]", "</b>", $txt);
echo $newtxt;
```

this would produce:

not bold **Yes Bold** not bold again

Comment: The double asterisk seems more elegant … its not only less to write but also you can switch seamlessly to markdown.

Comment: @JohannesGrandy My answer only serves as a starting point for ideas since you could implement features not readily available in markdown. If you want a full-fledged markdown conversion using PHP then just get something pre-built such as https://parsedown.org/